# SQL Server Query that identifies missing data for specific dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains data that needs to be checked periodically throughout the day in order to ensure that it is being updated properly.

Every single day this table should be inserted with data like so:

```
           CORRECT
|  Date  |  Unit  |  Paid  |
| 1/1/12 | Unit A |  YES   |
| 1/1/12 | Unit B |  YES   |
| 1/2/12 | Unit A |  NO    |
| 1/2/12 | Unit B |  NO    |
```

So there should be data for each day for unit A and unit B. However, sometimes my program doesn't return data properly and I end up missing data for some dates or receive data for a date, but only for one unit:

```
          INCORRECT
|  Date  |  Unit  |  Paid  |
| 1/1/12 | Unit A |  YES   |
| 1/3/12 | Unit A |  NO    |
| 1/3/12 | Unit B |  NO    |
```

Data is missing 1/1/12 for Unit B. Data is missing 1/2/12 for Units A and B.

How could I write a query that would return the dates that are missing data and for which units it's missing data?

Comment: What would be your expected result in this case?

Comment: @wewesthemenace Well the bottom table is incorrect, so it should return that Unit B is missing data for 1/1/12, unit A and B are missing for 1/2/12.

Comment: Search for calendar table

Comment: Is it always going to be just `unit a` and `unit b`? or can there be other unit values?

Comment: @ZoharPeled it will always be unit a and unit b.

Comment: some what similar question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329722/sql-server-displaying-missing-dates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to generate all combinations of `Date` and `Unit`. After you get all the combinations, you can use `NOT EXISTS` to get the missing data.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3e88/3/0)

```
DECLARE @minDate AS DATE
DECLARE @maxDate AS DATE

SELECT
    @minDate = MIN([Date]),
    @maxDate = MAX([Date])
FROM TestData


;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @minDate, @maxDate) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteDatesAndUnits([Date], Unit) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, t.N - 1, @minDate),
        u.Unit
    FROM Tally t
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Unit FROM TestData
    )u
)
SELECT *
FROM CteDatesAndUnits c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM TestData
    WHERE
        [Date] = c.[Date]
        AND Unit = c.Unit
)
```

**Result**

```
|       Date |   Unit |
|------------|--------|
| 2012-01-01 | Unit B |
| 2012-01-02 | Unit A |
| 2012-01-02 | Unit B |
```

---

Since the `Unit` will always be `Unit A` and `Unit B`, you can replace this line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Unit FROM TestData
```

with this:

```
SELECT 'Unit A' AS Unit UNION ALL SELECT 'Unit B'
```

Comment: This is totally what I'm looking for! I made a super simple example of what I needed, but let's say it's a list of over 700 possibilities?

Comment: What if it were like Unit A, Type A, Unit A, Type B, and so on?

Comment: Then use the `SELECT DISTINCT` to get all `Units`.

Comment: What about the 700 possibilities? What do you mean by that?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Be sure to read the article referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in that case I would probably do something like this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate date, @ToDate date 

-- Or you can use Max and Min date from your table
SELECT @FromDate = '2015-01-01',
       @ToDate = '2015-01-07'

-- use a recursive cte to get all the dates between from date and to date
;With CTE AS (
  SELECT @FromDate As TheDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateAdd(Day, 1, TheDate)
  FROM CTE
  WHERE TheDate < @ToDate
)

-- select dates where all the units are missing
SELECT TheDate, 'All' as Missing_Units
FROM CTE 
LEFT JOIN YourTable ON(YourTable.Date = CTE.TheDate)
WHERE Unit IS NULL

UNION ALL

-- select dates where 'Unit B' is missing
SELECT T1.Date, 'Unit B' as Missing_Units
FROM YourTable T1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Date, Unit
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Unit = 'Unit B'
 ) T2 ON(T1.Date = T2.Date)
WHERE T2.Unit IS NULL

UNION ALL

-- select dates where 'Unit A' is missing
SELECT T1.Date, 'Unit A' as Missing_Units
FROM YourTable T1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Date, Unit
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Unit = 'Unit A'
 ) T2 ON(T1.Date = T2.Date)
WHERE T2.Unit IS NULL
```

[See fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ae7c1/24)

Comment: I would suggest against using a recursive `CTE` to generate all dates. Read this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/) by Jeff Moden for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link! recursive cte does seem to have poor performance, I'll go with your suggestion from now on.