# Account for missing values in group by month

Tags: sql

I'm trying to retrieve the average number of records added to the database each month. However for months that no records were added, the row is missing and therefore not being calculated into the average.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT AVG(a.count) AS AVG
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, MONTH(InsertedTimestamp) AS Month
    FROM Certificates
    WHERE InsertedTimestamp >= '9/19/2014'
        AND InsertedTimestamp <= '7/1/2015'
    GROUP BY MONTH(InsertedTimestamp)

) AS a
```

When I run just the inner query, only results from months 9,10,11 are showing, because there are no records for months 12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7. How can I add these missing rows to the table in order to get the correct monthly average?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server displaying missing dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329722/sql-server-displaying-missing-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough to fix, just by using sum / cnt:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, '2014-09-19', '2015-07-01' ) + 1)
  FROM Certificates
  WHERE InsertedTimestamp >= '2014-09-19'  AND
        InsertedTimestamp <= '2015-07-01' ;
```

You don't even need the subquery.

Comment: There are 11 different months, September to July inclusive: what does the TIMESTAMPDIFF() expression return? 10, 11 or a noninteger value? The correct value for the purpose of computing an average is 11.

Comment: It seems that the TIMESTAMPDIFF function is being difficult. I had to add a 1 to the end of it to get the number I was looking for. Thank you very much, that's a pretty fancy way of doing it :)

Comment: @LorenzoGatti it was returning 10, when i needed 11